# Phantom.js doesn't run from the OSX console

Tags: javascript, macos, console, extjs, phantomjs

I'm developing an ExtJS app and I'd like to render the view as pdf using Phantom.js. I've downloaded binary package for OSX, after unpacking added a symlink to it as well as added it to the PATH. After running 'phantomjs' in the console I get :

```
phantomjs script.js
```

And that's all. When I try running any of the example scripts it crashes saying that `require is undefined`, I can't check the version and basically it's unusable. I can run the bat file though, and it gives me phantomjs shell. After removing all I've downloaded previously I can still run 'phantomjs' command with the same outcome. Probably because Sencha's SDK have it but it's not visible in the PATH so I'm not sure. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as always found the problem seconds after submitting question. Sencha's SDK had some custom or broken version of phantomjs.bat, and the whole folder was added to the PATH.